# Logging delays when using Log4j

Tags: windows, log4j, tomcat6, tomcat7

I am using log4j for logging purposes in Tomcat6 on a Windows Server [2008]. I have defined the appenders and loggers properly. Logger for org.apache logger is defined and I am getting the output in the log properly. The issue is, logging by the webapp deployed is delayed in output.

The whole logging by the webapp is being logged all at once, when the startup is complete. Under normal logging (using tomcat's juli/logging.properties), logging statements are logged as the startup progresses, but that's not the case with log4j logging.

For another webapp [which uses servicemix components] the logging works fine and there are no delays. I have tried with BufferedIO set to false [tried setting it to true as well, just for checking] and ImmediateFlush [true and false, tries both] as well, but the result is still the same.

Can anybody help me with this, I am really baffled!

Note: I have tried with Tomcat7 as well and got the same results, i.e. logging delays.

Thanks

Noman A.

Comment: There is a setting in log4net called BufferSize that when the number of logs reaches that level, log4net will then go ahead and perform the log. It sounds similar to the ImmediateFlush you identified above so maybe you already hit it.

Comment: Yes, that does sound similar to ImmediateFlush, also the BufferedIO is set to false, so I think it should not buffer at all, and output the data in log, but I am wondering how to resolve this! Thanks for the comment!